# Loading a properties file from Java package

Tags: java, properties-file

I need to read a properties files that's buried in my package structure in `com.al.common.email.templates`.

I've tried everything and I can't figure it out.

In the end, my code will be running in a servlet container, but I don't want to depend on the container for anything. I write JUnit test cases and it needs to work in both.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

When loading the Properties from a Class in the package `com.al.common.email.templates` you can use

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties");
prop.load(in);
in.close();
```

(Add all the necessary exception handling).

If your class is not in that package, you need to aquire the InputStream slightly differently:

```
InputStream in = 
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/al/common/email/templates/foo.properties");
```

Relative paths (those without a leading '/') in `getResource()`/`getResourceAsStream()` mean that the resource will be searched relative to the directory which represents the package the class is in.

Using `java.lang.String.class.getResource("foo.txt")` would search for the (inexistent) file `/java/lang/String/foo.txt` on the classpath.

Using an absolute path (one that starts with '/') means that the current package is ignored.

Comment: Suggestion: Add an explanation when to use relative and when to use absolute paths (with and without the "/" at the beginning).

Comment: what if your properties file is outside the src directory but still inside your project director?

Comment: @jonney: Java itself has no notion of "project directory", some IDEs might have that. But as far as Java is concerned then it's simply a file somewhere on the file system with no relation to the classpath at all.

Answer (score 51):

To add to Joachim Sauer's answer, if you ever need to do this in a static context, you can do something like the following:

```
static {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  InputStream in = CurrentClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.properties");
  prop.load(in);
  in.close()
}
```

(Exception handling elided, as before.)

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. I could not get the accepted answer to work.

Comment: @cobralibre how read a properties file which resides in `resources` folder in a `maven` project

Answer (score 16):

The following two cases relate to loading a properties file from an example class named `TestLoadProperties`.

**Case 1: Loading the properties file using `ClassLoader`**

```
InputStream inputStream = TestLoadProperties.class.getClassLoader()
                          .getResourceAsStream("A.config");
properties.load(inputStream);
```

In this case the properties file must be in the `root/src` directory for successful loading.

**Case 2: Loading the properties file without using `ClassLoader`**

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("A.config");
properties.load(inputStream);
```

In this case the properties file must be in the same directory as the `TestLoadProperties.class` file for successful loading.

**Note:** `TestLoadProperties.java` and `TestLoadProperties.class` are two different files. The former, `.java` file, is usually found in a project's `src/` directory, while the latter, `.class` file, is usually found in its `bin/` directory.

Answer (score 12):

```
public class Test{  
  static {
    loadProperties();
}
   static Properties prop;
   private static void loadProperties() {
    prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = Test.class
            .getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
public class ReadPropertyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(
                    "com/technicalkeeda/demo/application.properties"));
            System.out.println("Domain :- " + properties.getProperty("domain"));
            System.out.println("Website Age :- "
                    + properties.getProperty("website_age"));
            System.out.println("Founder :- " + properties.getProperty("founder"));

            // Display all the values in the form of key value
            for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println("Key:- " + key + "Value:- " + value);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using the [Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class, via its [load](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) method, and I guess you are using the ClassLoader [getResourceAsStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to get the input stream.

How are you passing in the name, it seems it should be in this form: `/com/al/common/email/templates/foo.properties`

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentions the similar but even simpler solution than above with no need to deal with the package of the class. Assuming myfile.properties is in the classpath.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myfile.properties");
        properties.load(in);
        in.close();
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue with this call

```
Properties props = PropertiesUtil.loadProperties("whatever.properties");
```

Extra, you have to put your whatever.properties file in /src/main/resources

Comment: Where are you getting `PropertiesUtil` from?

Answer (score -2):

use the below code please :

```
    Properties p = new Properties(); 
    StringBuffer path = new StringBuffer("com/al/common/email/templates/");
    path.append("foo.properties");
    InputStream fs = getClass().getClassLoader()
                                    .getResourceAsStream(path.toString());
```

`if(fs == null){
     System.err.println("Unable to load the properties file");
  }
else{
   try{
       p.load(fs);
     } 
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }`