# Can't find property files on classpath

Tags: java, properties, glassfish, classpath

I'm trying to load/read property files on glassfish 3.1 server. 
I can't get it to work. I've searched and tried many possible solutions.
None worked so far, always NULL as result.

I've tried methods from the following link:
[How to use a property with Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531593/how-to-use-a-property-file-with-glassfish)

My method:

```
final public class GTS_Properties{

...

   public static Properties getPropertiesFromFile(String fileName){
      URL url = GTS_Properties.class.getResource(fileName)
      ...
      // url is always null
   }
}
```

My configuration:
Folder properties on build path.

> /root/WEB-INF/classes/****.properties

How the Glassfish server looks like (using eclipse startup plugin)

> /glassfish-root/domain/eclipseApps/MyWebApp/WEB-INF/classes/****.properties

I have tried to put the property files directly in WEB-INF instead of classes. same result.

Comment: You make it difficult to help you by not specifying the path you are using to load the resource. Note that the path will be different depending on which Class you are using as context for loading the resource.

Comment: You mean the relative path from the class im trying to open it from? 
in my case: WEB-INF/classes/WebApp/utils/GTS_Properties.class
and : WEB-INF/classes/****.properties

i should use then the path like GTS_Properties.class.getResource("../../" + fileName)

OK, this works. thanks!

Comment: What is the exact fileName you use? where is exactly your property file? what is the package of GTS_Properites?

Comment: @WvdL - when you use a specific class to load a resource, the resource path is specified relative to *the class*. However, if you were to use the context classloader of the thread (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource`), then the resource path is specified relative to the *root of the classpath*. Good rules to keep in mind, though it seems you have gotten around the problem?

Comment: yes it works now Perception. I used my class as starting point to create the path to the property file. I always thought i had to use the root of the classpath as starting point. Thanks for clearing up this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first going 2 'parent folders up' from the startpoint of the relative path.
Inserting "../../" on the start of the path was all that was needed.

WEB-INF/classes/WebApp/utils/GTS_Properties.class **(The class to get the resource from)**
WEB-INF/classes/prop.properties      **(Location of the resource file)**

```
GTS_Properties.class.getResource("../../prop.properties")
```