# Cannot find database.properties when trying to deploy server

Tags: java

Hello I am new to java development, I am trying to modify an application developed by a colleague however when I try to deploy it I get this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error building SqlSession.
>
> #### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration
>
> #### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find
>
> resource database.properties
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error building SqlSession.
>
> #### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration
>
> #### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find
>
> resource database.properties
>     org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
>     org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:79)
>     org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:67)
>     com.jeeutils.db.ConnectionBuilderAction.(ConnectionBuilderAction.java:30)
>     com.jeeutils.db.ConnectionBuilderAction.getSqlSession(ConnectionBuilderAction.java:45)
>     com.utils.dbsession.DbSession.newSessionKey(DbSession.java:47)
>     com.utils.dbsession.DbSession.getSession(DbSession.java:147)
>     com.webapp.actions.BusinessAction.loadProfileMenuList(BusinessAction.java:391)
>     com.webapp.actions.BusinessAction.preprocessRequest(BusinessAction.java:158)
>     com.webapp.actions.LoginAction.addForm(LoginAction.java:56)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:140)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:158)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:343)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:237)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:211)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:982)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I would like to know what the cause of this error is and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[Ibatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) is a data mapping framework (it is in the middle between your database and the object oriented logic... provides object in return of a query) and it does have a configuration file and this "database.properties". Once deployed, your program cannot find it. I can't tell you more without knowing more details.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531593/how-to-use-a-property-file-with-glassfish) could help too, the response suggest a place where the property file could be placed.

Comment: Found the configuration file however I noticed it is src/main/local/ and mybatisConfig.xml has the following property <properties resource="database.properties" />.  What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Hey at least he made an effort. I'm grateful.  His info was very useful.

Comment: Well I posted an answer because it is at least a partial answer. He asked what is the cause (and gave him an answer) and how to solve it (and I couldn't answer on this, I agree)

Comment: There's no denying It may have helped, and of course it is to be commended that Marco offered what he could - but it is still not an answer.  According to SO guidelines, commentary, requests for clarification, links, background info, etc should be posted as comments, not answers.