# How to load property file from classpath?

Tags: java

`getResourceAsStream()` is the method of `java.lang.Class` class. This method finds the resource with given name into the classpath. Actually this method delegates to this object's class loader. In this example `PropUtil` object's class loader. But before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using following algorithm.

Comment: ... huh? Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package

Answer (score 78):

If you use the static method and load the properties file from the classpath folder so you can use the below code :

```
//load a properties file from class path, inside static method
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(Classname.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties"));
```

Comment: Does the `InputStream` opened by `getResourceAsStream` need to be closed after loaded ?

Comment: @CDT The `Properties.load()` javadoc states that "_The specified stream remains open after this method returns._"

Answer (score 65):

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
try (final InputStream stream =
           this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties")) {
    properties.load(stream);
    /* or properties.loadFromXML(...) */
}
```

Comment: Does the `InputStream` opened by `getResourceAsStream` need to be closed after loaded ?

Comment: @CDT The `Properties.load()` javadoc states that "_The specified stream remains open after this method returns._"

Comment: This is the "try with resources" syntax introduced with Java 7.  The stream will be automatically closed when the try {} block exits.  Prior to Java 7, you would close this stream by hand in a finally {} block.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @DrewWills yes, we know; the comments were regarding the original code posted which did not use the Java 7 *try-with-resources* construct

Comment: In my experience, the file needs a leading "/" to be found from the classpath.

Comment: Won't really work in every case if you don't call the method through the class loader instead of the class itself.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli don't know if that's true in practice but if so that behavior violates the [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))--*This method delegates to this object's class loader.*

Comment: @oldrinb : I am getting FileNotFoundException. My file is at projectName/config.properties...