# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at UserDaoImpl.<clinit>(UserDaoImpl.java:71)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, junit4

It's my testHelper:

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml" })

    public class TestHelper {

        @Mock
        private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
        @InjectMocks
        private Helper helper=new Helper();

        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        String msg = "Success";
        int status = 200;
        ResponseMessage message = new ResponseMessage();

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(helper).build();
        }

        @Test
            public void testCategories() throws Exception {
            message = helper.getCategories(0);
            assertNotNull(message);
            Assert.assertEquals(status, message.getStatus());
            Assert.assertEquals(msg, message.getMessage());
        }   }
```

It's my Helper class:

```
public class Helper extends BaseHelper {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(Helper.class);

    public ResponseMessage getCategories(int categoryID) {
        logger.info("**Helper getCategories() entry*****");
        ResponseMessage message;
        try {
            List<Category> categories = userDao
                    .getCategories(categoryID);
            String jsonConverted = Utility
                    .convertToJsonString(categories);
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
            Object obj = mapper
                    .readValue(
                            jsonConverted,
                            new TypeReference<List<Category>>() {
                            });
            message = prepareResponse(obj, 200, "Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("****Exception in Helper getCategories() : "
                    + e.getStackTrace());

            message = prepareResponse( null, 500,
                    e.getMessage());

        }
        logger.info("***Helper getCategories() exit****");
        return message;
    }
}
```

It's my UserDaoImpl class:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private static Properties applicationProperties;

    static {
        applicationProperties = Utility.loadAppProperties();
    }
    public List<Category> getCategories(int category_id) {
        Session session = null;
        List<Category> categories = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            logger.info("enter into getCategories from  method's body");
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            if (!Utility.isZeroInt(category_id)) {
                List list = session.createCriteria(Category.class).add(Restrictions.eq("category_id", category_id))
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
                categories = list;
            } else {
                List list = session.createCriteria(Category.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                        .list();
                categories = list;
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataException("Unable to get categories. Please try after some time.");
        }
        logger.info("exit from getCategories method's body");
        return categories;
    }
}
```

When i test my helper class then i got the error on the `applicationProperties = Utility.loadAppProperties();` in the userdaoimpl class. and the error is
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`. This error are generate at the time of load the property file in userdaoimpl class.

> this is the stack trace

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.zon.dao.UserDaoImpl.<clinit>(UserDaoImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:111)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:51)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:54)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:44)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:882)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.processAnnotationOn(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:34)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.scan(MockitoAnnotations.java:110)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:95)
    at com.zon.testHelper.TestHelper.setup(TestHelper.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.zon.utils.Utility.<clinit>(Utility.java:27)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: Please share stack trace.

Comment: The error is possibly in `applicationProperties = Utility.loadAppProperties();` and you need to look at stackTrace to tell what in `loadAppProperties` has caused the error. I am guessing there is a missing resource file; stack trace is important as @shankarsh15 mentioned for any accurate analysis.

Comment: Hi @shankarsh... now i have attached trace. u cn check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

The above exception says its not able to find Properties file.Try to put properties file at the root of the classpath.

Comment: Hello @shankarsh.... there is any way to ignore the "applicationProperties = Utility.loadAppProperties();" in userdaoimpl. because i give properly classpath of the property file.but not able to load property file when i called    from the test case.

Comment: Please follow this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024672/how-to-load-property-file-from-classpath

Comment: i hv to do same thing.

Comment: static {
  applicationProperties = new Properties();
  InputStream applicationPropertiesInputStream = null;
  try
  {
   applicationPropertiesInputStream = Utility.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"); 
   applicationProperties.load(applicationPropertiesInputStream);
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
   exception.printStackTrace();
  }}