# how to read properties file in spring project?

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-annotations

Before post this Question, I google to get Properties from Spring project(Its NOT web-based project). I am confused as every one are talking about application-context.xml and have configuration like

However, I am working on normal Java Project with Spring(NO Web-app and stuff like that). But I would like to get some common properties from properties file and that needs to be used in JAVA file. How can achieve this by using Spring/Spring Annotations?

Where I should configure myprops.properties file under my project and how to invoke through spring?

My understanding is application-context.xml is used ONLY for web based projects. If not, how should I configure this application-context.xml as I do NOT have web.xml to define the application-context.xml

Comment: How do you define your Spring context? Every Spring app has a Spring context.

Comment: XML configuration is not just for web based projects

Comment: Yes. You are correct. My question would be where exactly that XML file needs to be place under the project workspace(spring.xml or other.xml) in Java project

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create an XML based application context like:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("conf/appContext.xml");
```

if the xml file is located on your class path. Alternatively, you can use a file on the file system:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("conf/appContext.xml");
```

More information is available in the [Spring reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx). You should also register a [shutdown hook](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown) to ensure graceful shutdown:

```
 ctx.registerShutdownHook();
```

Next, you can use the [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) to extract the properties from a '.properties' file and inject them into your beans:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Lastly, if you prefer annotation based config, you can use the `@Value` annotation to inject properties into you beans:

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    @Value("${jdbc.url}") 
    private String jdbcUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how to get the properties from java code?

Comment: If you would like to populate a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/333385/303598) (don't forget to add the `finally` block to close the stream).

Comment: Wonderful explanation. I really appreciate the response and your time. But I have simple question like where that XML mapping needs to be done under Workspace(spring.xml or application-context.xml or other.xml) What is the best way to name the XML file and what would be the top level schema for that?

Comment: Afaik, there is no general rule, but here are some suggestions. For a small project, I think your suggestions spring.xml or application-context.xml make sense. For larger projects that consists of several sub-projects, I would probably name them according to the subdomain, e.g. core-context.xml, backend-context.xml, client-context.xml, etc. If you for some reason would like to externalize the database config, db-context.xml and so on...

Comment: I am developing a standalone java application , packaged as JAR. I have to provide properties file outside o JAR i.e. properties file will reside beside jar file. How Can i give path of this property file?

Comment: you can use System.getProperty("user.dir"). this gives you the working path.you can keep your file and you can read the file from above path

Comment: we have multipe property files in our project and each server picks up the property file(local.properties, beta.properties,staging.properties) depending on the environment string -DAPPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE. In this case, what location can I add in this line ?  <property name="locations" value="classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties"/>

Answer (score 7):

As of Spring 4, you can use the [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation in a Spring `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    // more config ...
}
```

If you would like to have your config outside of your classpath, you can use the `file:` prefix:

```
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/application.properties")
```

Alternatively, you can use an environmental variable to define the file

```
@PropertySource("file:${APP_PROPERTIES}")
```

Where `APP_PROPERTIES` is an environmental variable that has the value of the location of the property file, e.g. `/path/to/application.properties`.

Please read my blog post [Spring @PropertySource](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/) for more information about `@PropertySource`, its usage, how property values can be overridden and how optional property sources can be specified.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use Spring.
You can read with plain java like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you figure out how your project will be used in the whole app? If your project is used as a build path for a web app and the configuration in your project is achieved through spring annotations, so no doubt you are puzzled about how to add an `application.xml` file. My suggest is you have to announce the guys who will use your project, tell them what you need and you just need to add `@Value("${valuename}")` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Create new property file inside your *`src/main/resources/`* directory and file extension must be *`.properties`* e.g. *`db.properties`***

Write following context properties in your spring xml configuration file:

*`<context:property-placeholder location="db.properties"/>`*

**Usage:** *`${property-key}`*