# null values for property in spring junit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I am writing Junit for my Spring 4 application where I am using test.properties file from src/test/resources directory for test properties as below

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties" />
```

Below is my Junit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:spring-servlet.xml")
public class MyHandlerTest {

}
```

In my application I have classes which has @Service annotation as below

```
@Service
public class MyHandler {
  @Inject
  Environment env;
  //rest of the code
}
```

When in my handler I am trying to get property as

```
env.getProperty("someProperty");
```

I am getting null value here, so my problem is how I can access properties from all my classes?

**Update**

I got confuse, actually null pointer is because of it is not Autowring the interface, I have

```
@Service
public class MyHandler {
  @Inject
  Environment env;

  @Autowired
  Util util;

  //rest of the code
}
```

Where I am getting null for util, can somebody let me know how Autowired interface works in Junit, from spring-servlet.xml file I am scanning all packages but still Autowire is null.

Comment: try with this, `@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")`

Comment: If your project structure is `maven` then keep `test.properties` file in, something like this `src/main/resources/config/test.properties`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring jUnit Testing properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974432/spring-junit-testing-properties-file) also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test

Comment: You should add `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean also.