# Class getResourceAsStream() resource in a different package

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader

I have something like the following project structure

```
-project 
    -src/main/java // source folder
        -com.mypackage
            -Utility.java
            -some.properties
    -src/main/resources // source folder
        -configuration_files
            -configuration_report.txt
```

I'm generating the `jar` with Eclipse's `Export` function. The above translates to a `jar` with the structure:

```
-myjar.jar
    -com
        -mypackage
            -Utility.class
            -some.properties
    -configuration_files
        -configuration_report.txt
```

Within the `Utility` class, I'm trying to get the `InputStream` from `configuration_report.txt`.

I was doing this (it's within a `static` method):

```
Utility.class.getResourceAsStream("/configuration_files/configuration_report.txt");
```

which seems to be validated by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package), since the file is not in the same package as the class requesting it.

When I run it, however, it returns `null`. Why?

Note that for the `some.properties` file, I could do both

```
Utility.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/package/some.properties");
Utility.class.getResourceAsStream("some.properties");
```

and I would get the stream.

I'm running this from the command line if it makes any difference.

```
java [-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044] -cp myjar.jar MyMain
```

If I try to run it within Eclipse, it works...

**Edit:**

This code is relevant. With or without the preceding `/`, it return null

```
    String sourceFilePath = "/configuration_files" + File.separator + "configuration_report.txt";
    InputStream in = Utility.class.getResourceAsStream(sourceFilePath);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many tries, the solution comes down to this little javadoc entry for [`ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29):

> The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.

The snippet I had originally posted would've worked

```
Utility.class.getResourceAsStream("/configuration_files/configuration_report.txt");
```

but I wasn't using `/`, I was using `File.separator` like in my edit:

```
String sourceFilePath = "/configuration_files" + File.separator + "configuration_report.txt";
```

thinking the class loader worked like OS specific File operations. The first `/` was matched, but the `File.separator` evaluated to `\\` since I'm on Windows.

The javadoc for [`Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) says more of the same.

> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

As to why this worked on Eclipse, but not from the command line, I'm still unsure, but look at @andy's comment below.

This [article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2006/12/how_to_use_file_separator_when/) gives is a good explanation of this situation.

Comment: I try using '\\', when extract jar to a folder and run java -cp . Main it works but not works in jar. I think '\\' works in folder because the class loader can find the path "configuration_files\\configuration_report.txt" in real folder but cannot in jar.