# GWT Application Configuration File

Tags: c#, xml, spring, gwt, config

I am really confused and hoping someone can give some direction. I am working on a GWT Spring application and want to store some application specific data  in an xml config file which can be accessed on the server side. How and where should I store this and how can I access this data.

I want to do the same thing that the appSettings.config does in c#.net.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
war/WEB-INF
```

That folder is accessible by the server-side code, but not any clients over the internet.

**Sources**:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/source.html#Directory_Structure
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/basics.html#136976

**Reading the file**

I suggest storing your configuration in a Java Properties file (eg: config.properties). That way you can load and read easily using `java.util.Properties`, [as described on this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package).

`java.util.Properties` also lets you [load from an XML file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29).