# Where should application.properties file get stored?

Tags: java, maven

In a java project where does the application.properties file commonly get stored?

Comment: resources/META-INF/config

Answer (score 1):

I store my application properties in src.main.resources. Resources package is quite self-explanatory and property files can be easily found there for everyone who looks at this project for the first time. Resouces are stored in main package in case you need different configuration for your tests, therefore I have also src.test.resources package.

Answer (score 0):

In a **JAVA** project you can keep the properties files wherever you want, as long as you can find them during runtime.

Take a look at this question for more details: [Loading a properties file from Java package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package)

For a **MAVEN** project:

You can of course override this, but normally properties files in maven projects are kept in specific places:

Configuration used during runtime is kept in src/main/resources.

Configuration used during tests is kept in src/test/resources.