# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, properties

I am using config.properties file in order to set port. After running I am facing an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>
> java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) at
>
> java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) at
>
> java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) at
>
> HttpServer.setPort(HttpServer.java:83) at
>
> HttpServer.(HttpServer.java:26)

The main class:

```
public class HttpServer {

    static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", SSL ? "8443" : setPort()));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpServer httpServer = new HttpServer();
        httpServer.start();
    }

    public void start(){}

    public static String setPort() {
        String port = "";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/config.properties"));
            port = properties.getProperty("server.port");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return port;
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand what is the error...

Comment: What do you think `getResourceAsStream("src/main/config.properties")` does and why do you think so?

Comment: please refer to this answer on how to read properties file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your code is in a maven project. As such,

1. place your properties file in `src/main/resources/config.properties`
2. use `getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")`

When doing a maven build, maven will package your jar and make the resources part of the classpath. Anything in `resources/` will be part of the classpath root, since I start it with a slash when I use the `getResourceAsStream`.

You could also have simply called:
`HttpServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")` instead.

Note that you open a InputStream, and pass it to `Properties.load()`. This will leave the stream open. Better to do something like:

```
try (InputStream is = HttpServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties") ) {
  properties.load(is);
}
```

The Try-With-Resources will take care of closing the input stream no matter what ( even in case of an error/exception).

Many do not do that, and even I leave it open for short running programs ... But yours suggests it is a HTTP Server ... so better to be more sensitive about these mattes ... connection leaks, file handle leaks, memory leaks, etc. Eventually it might get garbage collected, but better not to depend on it.