# how to read values from property file?

Tags: java, properties-file

How to read the values from properties file in java script?

I goggling about it but not satisfied.Please share me some samples or links. My application develops by jsp-servlet, eclipse LUNA and Windows7.

Comment: you cant read in javascript. it has to be read in Java.

Comment: Then what would be the efficient way to read in java and and use the value in jsp / java script ?

Comment: you can use the one i have mentioned in the ans

Answer (score 1):

You can read property file in many way, below is one of the way. [Good Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package)

**config.properties**

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=mkyong
```

**App.java**

```
package com.mkyong.properties;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
}
```

[Google Links](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHNQ_enIN613IN613&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read%20properties%20file%20in%20java)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is executed on the client side and cannot access local files (except the html5 web storage).

If you want to access properties which are defined in a properties file on the server side you have two options:

**Server side parsing**

Read the properties file at the server side and write the values to the html response as JS values

```
// output a property as JS value to the client. Make sure this is inside a 
// <script> tag
void printProperty(Properties properties, String key) {
   Sytem.out.println("var " + key + "='"properties.getProperty("key") + "'");
}
```

**Client side parsing (more complex)**

1. Make the properties file available through an URL (http:/.../conf.properties)
2. Read the file via ajax
3. Parse the properties file