# How to save an image to SQL server with java? when the image is in package of my project

Tags: java, sql, image, image-uploading

I am creating an application where the user can add profiles of different person including his profile picture. However i want to enable the option when there is NO picture to upload. In that way i want to save a default image that it is in package of my project. [image in a package of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVAPZ.png)

Here is part of the code that i use to save a picture using FileChooser i might be almost the same i think.

```
String F = TxtRutaFoto.getText();
FileInputStream fis = null; 
try{
File file = new File(F);   
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
int k = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "DESEA GUARDAR LOS DATOS DEL JUGADOR?","PREGUNTA", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(k == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){   try (
CallableStatement pstm = conexion.conectar.getConnection().prepareCall("{call INSERTARJUGADOR(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")
             ){
pstm.setString(1, txtID.getText());
pstm.setString(2, txt_ape_pat.getText());
pstm.setString(3, txt_ape_mat.getText());
pstm.setString(4, txt_nombre.getText());
pstm.setString(5, txt_correo.getText());
pstm.setString(6, txt_direc.getText());
pstm.setBinaryStream(7, fis, (int) file.length());
ResultSet r = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Comment: so the question is: how do I load resources from the classpath? see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/333385/3959856

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `InputStream` of the picture in your jar. You can do that by using the method `classLoader#getResource` method:

```
String loc = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/path/to/resource.jpg");
InputStream is = new URL(loc).openStream();
```

In the default-case you can set that stream instead of the `FileInputStream`. You should check `loc` for being null in case the file can't be found (sometimes you have to leave the leading slash away.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i used this and its works. First i create a 'resources' folder in where is my default picture. Then i just i used the next code.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/user.jpg").getFile());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

then i just call my procedure

```
pstm.setBinaryStream(7, fis);
ResultSet r = pstm.executeQuery();
```