# Implement a tier-specific structure for `.properties` files

Tags: java, properties, properties-file, spark-java

I'm trying to implement a tier-specific fallback system for my properties.

I know more advanced frameworks like Spring have built in support for this, but I'm using the more minimal Spark Java framework.

Say I have the following structure -

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
      properties/
        dev/
          |- application.properties
          |- ValidationMessages.properties
          |- log4j.properties
        prod/
          |- application.properties
          |- ValidationMessages.properties
          |- log4j.properties
        test/
          |- application.properties
          |- ValidationMessages.properties
          |- log4j.properties

        application.properties
        ValidationMessages.properties
        log4j.properties
```

I'd like properties to be sourced as follows. Assume I have a system config `APP.TIER` that lets me know at runtime what the current tier is (`test`, `dev`, `prod`, etc...)

1. Any top-level "shared" file (e.g. `properties/application.properties`) should apply to all tiers
2. Any tier-specific properties in (e.g. `properties/${APP.TIER}/application.properties`) should override common values

With application properties at least I can load them programmatically at the start of my `main()` method and have them available app wide ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333363/loading-a-properties-file-from-java-package)). I can also control the order in which they get loaded so I ensure I manually apply the above fallback logic.

However for 3rd party plugins (e.g. `ValidationMessages.properties` used by Hibernate or `log4j.properties` used by log4j) I don't have control over how the properties are loaded.

Is there a generic framework that supports this type of property sourcing? I know maven supports profiles and filtering but that means I'll have to build a separate JAR file for each tier, which doesn't seem great practice.

Comment: Actually, the Properties class has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Properties%29) that accepts a fallback Properties object.  You can use that to build a fallback chain.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have been using when I mentioned I loaded the `applications.properties` programmatically. That works great. The issue is when other libraries load their configs, I have no control over what order and fallback logic they use. I know it's bad practice to circumvent their logic but I'm new to Java and i was wondering if this was a solved problem - i.e. is there a library or framework that implements fallbacks and serves it to the 3rd party plugin?